# Bootstrap column Border

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have taken `col-md-3` and `col-md-6` in a  `div` named 'left-area' in order to give border around `col-md-3` and `col-md-6` at a time. Rest of `col-md-3` will get border but it is not problem. Problem in `col-md-3` and `col-md-6`. plz check my markup.

```css
 .left-area{ border:2px solid #00FFCC}
 .rightsidebar-area{ border:2px solid #00FFCC}
```

```html
<section id="blog-area">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="left-area">
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <p>Feather images will goes here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <p>Blog content and post title  goes here.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="rightsidebar-area">
    <p>Rght sidebar link goes here.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What is your question and what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/josangel555/5wdaywt6/

```
 <div class="left-area col-md-9">
```

^ you missed the above column specification.

EDIT: based on comment.

Move the `rightsidebar-area` class to its parent (one with the `col-sm-3` class) and change the `container` class to  `container-fluid`.

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/josangel555/5wdaywt6/1/

Comment: Thanks for Reply.. This is also not working. remain some space in right side

Comment: that space is the result of padding added by `container` class that you added to a parent `div`. Remove that and you can remove the spacing..

Comment: pls check the upadted answer for a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .left-area {
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }

    .rightsidebar-area {
        border: none;
    }
</style>

<div class="row">
        <div class="left-area">

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p>Feather images will goes here.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>Blog content and post title  goes here.</p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="rightsidebar-area">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p>Rght sidebar link goes here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```